# Triple integral!

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Can we  imagine what the triple integral of  a function **F** is geometrically on a three dimensional region **B**?I know that if F=1 the triple integrall gives the volume of the region **B**.

Comment: Triple has a *single* p, not a double p. Please edit accordingly. Then you can work on "tree", "integrall", and "vollume".

Comment: most probably u meant "three" where u have written "tree".But such a integral, would certainly be a 4- dimensional volume(Hyper objects), Which i doubt one could imagine in present state Man normally lives in or if u like 'Normal State of Mind'

Comment: THats what i thought too.THanks ketan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interprete $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as the density, and $\int\int\int_B f(x,y,z) \mathrm{d}V$ would represent the mass of the object delimited by **B**.

Answer (score 0):

without going into the realm of Higher Dimensional Space. You could still understand triple integral in such a way say function F is denotes Temperature, at each point in region B. Then it would be practical for us